# How to use Debian in USB boot-able process

Tags: debian, system-installation, usb-drive

I am totally new to the Debian universe and want to use a USB stick so as to download, burn and then install Debian on a PC I got.

I read the documentation of Debian online (https://www.debian.org/CD/) although I would be grateful for some pointers.

First of all as advised I went to the download page and choose

```
Downloading Debian CD/DVD images via HTTP/FTP
```

I choose the most common distribution of amd64 DVD and got re-directed

```
http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.6.0/amd64/iso-dvd/
```

At this point I can see that there are three `.iso` Debian DVD's, my first question is which one should I use, from instinct I would say the 4.4Gb release?

I download the iso file, and here is where my lack of Linux knowledge kicks in, I insert the empty USB stick and open a Terminal there.
If I copy and paste the iso file in my USB stick, will it operate, probably not.

Continuing the exploration of the Debian website (https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch02s04.html.en#idp5731200)

I went to the USB section, although even through other Google searches, I don't understand how can I perform the creation of the Debian USB bootable.

the workstation I use now, is a cluster UNIX based, with scientific Linux 6, I tried to do it from my personal Windows laptop but the malware in some programs were annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For install linux distros on USB driver first you need to change the driver Format to `Ext4` then install debian as it is ! like on other place !

but in a simple way you can use [**Universal USB Installer**](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/). It is a Live Linux USB Creator that allows you to choose from a selection of Linux Distributions to put on your USB Flash Drive. The Universal USB Installer is easy to use. Simply choose a Live Linux Distribution, the ISO file, your Flash Drive and, Click Install.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most useful and easy software is http://unetbootin.net/ 
it's cross platform and can download ISO images from distro sites.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a UNIX system, writing an image directly to the USB stick is possible, which is easier. From [4.3.1](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch04s03.html.en#usb-copy-isohybrid) of the installation guide, run the following command in your terminal as root (where X is a letter from a to z and corresponds to your USB flash drive):

```
# cp <name of iso>.iso /dev/sdX
```

If somehow, this doesn't work for some reason, then you have to use another GNU/Linux system (like Debian and Fedora). If you really need to use your Windows for such task instead, you have to remove all the malware through an anti-virus program and use [Win32 Disk Imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) as recommended in the guide.